# error with adding data in DB

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am doing a theater online reservation systen and I am about to add seatid to mysql DB when user reserve.

this is my code to output id of seats when user click on button ShowNewSeat

```
  <input type="button" id="ShowNewSeat" value="Show Selected Seats" name="ShowNewSeat" />


$('#ShowNewSeat').click(function () {
            var str = [], seatid;
            $.each($('#place li.' + selectingSeatCss + ' a'), function (index, value) {
                seatid = $(this).attr('title');                   
                str.push(**seatid**);                   
            });
            alert(str.join(','));
        })
```

this code let user see the output of what seatid he clicked

now for the php file, i have used $_POST[] but it is not working, i need a way to add the **seatid** variable in a Database.

Appreciate any help guys...thnk u

Comment: Please stop using mysql_query & your code is vunerable to sql injections. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: i can't understand.. can you post the rest of the page?

Comment: please add the full addseat.php

Comment: most probably the `method="post"` in your form element is missing so it's sending the content of the form in `GET` parameter.

Comment: @TobiasZander

<?php
/* This code will make a connection with database */
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 
/* Now, we select the database */
mysql_select_db("test");
 
/* Now we will store the values submitted by form in variable */
$item=$_POST['ShowNewSeat'];

$insert_user=mysql_query("INSERT INTO seat (seatNo) VALUES ('$item')");
 
if($insert_user)
{ echo "Registration Succesfull"; 
 }
else
{ echo "error in registration".mysql_error(); }
 
/* closing the if else statements */
 
mysql_close($con);
?>

Comment: in the DB, it shows a successful add data but the value of seatid is 0

Comment: could you do a var_dump($_POST); to debug your post data?

Comment: what do you mean?? i believe the problem is with the variable that i should call

Answer (score 0):

Adding a var to an array in js does not send it 'to php'. You need to **submit** the form.

Note that $_POST[] does not contain data from get requests. Use $_GET[] or $_REQUEST[] instead.